# Oculus SDK 0.4.2 integration in existing DX Application (Render devices and all that)

Tags: c++, windows, dll, directx, oculus

I'm trying to integrate the new Oculus SDK (for the DK2) into Game Maker Studio.
I'm doing this by creating a DLL that communicates with GM and with the new SDK. I've come to a point where i just don't know what to do anymore.

Currently, i can get the oculus to turn on, and see the Health notice displayed in the oculus. The health display also seems to get drawn over the GM application window - after which the GM application draws itself over the window again - its like 2 applications are drawing in the same window.

The problem is, i need the application display to be fed into the DLL, parsed through there (to add distortion and some filters for the lenses of the oculus), and then spit it out into the Oculus device. The GM surface and oculus surface have to be combined and put in the oculus device.

I have 2 types of pointers availble - 1 for the HWND of the application (used [here](https://github.com/RobQuistNL/GMOculus/blob/master/DLL/GMOculus/GMOculus/main.cpp#L172)), and 1 DX Device pointer (i think, its used like so:

```
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;
GMEXPORT double LinkD3D( long POINTER ){
    d3ddev = (LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9)POINTER;

    // Enable 8x Anisotropic Filtering
    d3ddev->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAXANISOTROPY, 8);
    d3ddev->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_ANISOTROPIC);

    // Enable Linear Filtering
    d3ddev->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
    d3ddev->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
    return 1;
}
```

Now i wonder, how can i get that LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 into the DX11 stuff of the oculus SDK.

Currently i get the healthwarning to get drawn over the existing window.

I was thinking, maybe i need the internal texture (used above, d3ddev), and put it in the Ouculus pRender device, somewhere around here;
https://github.com/RobQuistNL/GMOculus/blob/master/DLL/GMOculus/GMOculus/main.cpp#L223

The source code of the project is found here; https://github.com/RobQuistNL/GMOculus/blob/master/DLL/GMOculus/GMOculus/main.cpp

I'm very sorry for the vague explaination, but please keep in mind that;

- Im actually a webdeveloper
- I use game maker for hobby games
- Know somewhat C++
- Have 0 experience with DX

I'm actually happy i can already get thehealth notice to draw on the oculus.

Its just that i can't seem to convert anything. I've tried textures, swapchains, render devices - but i keep getting errors. Am i looking in the wrong direction?

I am even willing to pay if someone can help me out.

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: You cannot obtain a Direct3D 9 device from a Direct3D 10 or 11 device. With DirectX 11.1, it is possible to obtain a mix of Direct3D 10.x and Direct3D 11.x devices, but not Direct3D 9. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404562.aspx#direct3d_device_sharing).

Comment: OK, So the fact that the code i showed, works as is, also implies that the window we're using is Direct3D 9? And the Oculus SDK implies its Direct3D 11.x ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using the Oculus SDK for anything else but retrieving the orientation? It's been some time, but last time I used it (a month or so after v1) I only needed to retrieve the orientation of the visor - the rest I did with whatever graphics API suited me.

Comment: Hi Simon, yeah, since the DK2 and the new SDK they have implemented "HMD access" - this means that the SDK handles the distortion shaders & filters, and outputs the window's content directly onto the rift device - without using it as an actual monitor. This allows for less latency, and keeps the game project clean and simple. I just wish that i could like grab the window's content, push it through the SDK, and let the SDK handle the rest.